# Remove an Array element

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, sizeof

So im trying to code a function to remove an element from an Array.for some reason i'm getting no errors but still does not print the result i need. i think the problem is in the function or data type declaration.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void deleteArray(char stra[ ], char ElementToRemove);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        char str[100];
        printf("Please Enter Array Elements\n");
        scanf("%s",&str);

        deleteArray(str, "a");
        printf("%s",&str);

    }
    return 0;
}


void deleteArray(char stra[ ], char ElementToRemove)
{
    int NumberOfElements = sizeof(stra);
    int ElementPos;

    for (int i = 0; i >= NumberOfElements;i++)
    {
        if (ElementToRemove == stra [i])
        {
            ElementPos = i;
        }
    }

    for (int SecondCounter = ElementPos; SecondCounter >= NumberOfElements;SecondCounter++ )
    {
        stra[SecondCounter] = stra[SecondCounter - 1];

    }

}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&str);`  --> `scanf("%99s",str);`

Comment: `printf("%s",&str);`  --> `printf("%s",str);`

Comment: `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` is *not* standard C

Comment: `deleteArray(str, "a");` --> `deleteArray(str, 'a');`

Comment: `@autoreleasepool` is Objective-C, not plain C.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, by passing the string literal `"a"`, you are essentially passing a `char*` type, so I think the parameter would resolve to part of the pointer address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many issues with your code, let's see them one by one.

1. When you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer to the first element of the array. So, `sizeof` in the `deleteArray()` function is not doing what you think it's doing there.

   You can use [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) instead to get the length of a `char` array. However, please note, this does not count the terminating null, anyways, and you need to *move* that one, too, to make the end of the modified array.
2. Then, in the `for` loop,

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i >= NumberOfElements;i++)  //false always....
   ```

   is wrong. I believe what you want is

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfElements;i++)
   ```
3. After that, regarding the call to the function should be

   ```
    deleteArray(str, 'a');  // 'a' is a char
   ```

   instead of

   ```
    deleteArray(str, "a"); // "a" denotes a string
   ```
4. Next, in the `main()` function, remove the `&` from the argument to `printf()`. It should look like

   ```
   printf("%s",str);
   ```
5. Also, to ensure safety from buffer overflow, you should make your`scanf()` to look like

   ```
   scanf("%99s",str);
   ```

Comment: You could also use `sizeof(stra)/sizeof(char)` to get the size of the array, right?

Comment: @mikeyq6 No, absolutely not. `stra` is essentially a pointer, not the array, and pointers and arrays nore **not** the same...

Answer (score 0):

If you need dynamically sized arrays, I recommend making them the last [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) (that wikipage has an example) of some (growable) `struct` and keep the size of that array in its containing `struct` ....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have array features, such as add, delete, move and so on, use linked lists. Linked lists are using pointers, so you can represent an array using them. This way it is possible to delete an element, move it or add a new one.

When declaring an array in c, you declare it fixed size. In your case, if you want not to use pointers and lists, you have to copy array elements to a new one, excluding the unneeded.